# System of Two equations with two unknowns of degree four

Tags: systems-of-equations, quartics

I am wondering if there is a direct way to solve exactly a system of two equations of this shape (the A to I are constants):

$Axy + Bxy^2 + Cx^2y + Dx^2y^2 + Ex^2 + Fy^2 + Gx + Hy + I=0$
this problem comes from a geometrical problem

Comment: From the way it looks, you could combine two equations to remove $x^2$ term.  Substitute $x$ equation in one original equation to get a sixth (?) degree equation in $y$.

Answer (score 1):

No, it is impossible to solve such a system **analytically** (which is what I presume you mean by "exactly").

To prove this, suppose that you had an oracle that could solve such a system analytically. You can then use this oracle to solve the quintic equation $Ax^5+Bx^4+Cx^3+Dx^2+Ex+F=0$, by asking the oracle for the solution to the system,

$$
\begin{eqnarray}
y&=&x^2 \\
0&=&Axy^2 + Bx^2y + Cxy + Dx^2 + Ex + F
\end{eqnarray}
$$

However, the quintic equation is not [solvable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel%E2%80%93Ruffini_theorem), so this oracle is a fraud.